# Firebase DatabaseURL - configuring firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use Firebase with my react app.

I have a file with the config as follows:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DB_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGE_ID,
}

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

const database = firebase.database();
const auth = firebase.auth()

export {firebase, auth, database };
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

> FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.  Be sure to include databaseURL option when calling firebase.initializeApp().

I can't understand this error because I have config included in the call to initialise the app. Config includes the database URL.

How do you initialise the database?

Answer (score 4):

Same issue here.
Context: Gatsby - gatsby-node.js

For SOME reason it dsnt like my env db url. need to hardcode just that value.

```
    const config = {
      apiKey: process.env.GATSBY_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
      authDomain: process.env.GATSBY_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
      databaseURL: "https://blabla.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: process.env.GATSBY_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      storageBucket: process.env.GATSBY_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
      messagingSenderId: process.env.GATSBY_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
    }
```

and it worked.

cya

Comment: Do you know the reason now? :)

Comment: While it's a workaround, it would've been nice to know why it does not work to access the value of this environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a copy paste error :)

in .env file
REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL

but i use
process.env.REACT_APP_DB

Please check it , it worked fine

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/database';
const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_SB,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_SID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MID
};


firebase.initializeApp(config);
const database = firebase.database();

export { database };
export default firebase;
```

Comment: Holy crap this was my exact issue and I'm literally kicking myself in the back for this. Thank you homie! life saver

Answer (score 2):

I know this a old thread, but I was facing this issue since last night and I spent hours racking my brain to figure out what was wrong with my code. To clarify, all .env variables were being read by cra except for the firebase database url.

I tried the following steps:

1. checked for spelling errors, both the .env variables and also to see if the url was correct, it was.
2. I tried printing the .env variables to console & screen both, but when I did the values were undefined *for all* env variables. This really should not happen and I was baffled.
3. Tried various things, changed the .env variable name for FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL to something random like XYZ (just to make it work somehow) as I thought some env variables were colliding due to same name, still didn't work.
4. The only way it worked was har-coding it, but this was an hack and not a solution.

The thing to note was point 2. When printing the env vars even after hardcoding the result was 'undefined' on console.
So nothing was wrong, the code should work, but it didn't why?
Out of pure randomness, I opened the task manager (windows). I notices node servers were running, but I had already closed the react dev server!
I killed the processes and restarted the react server, and now it was working.

The issue was stale node servers running in background and nothing was wrong with the code. This also resolved point 2, the console.log statements were working now.

This might not be solution to everyone's issues but it might be or *was* to the asker's question 3 yrs back, as there is nothing syntactically wrong with their code.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution for me too! I had to stop the development server that was running locally!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that `if` statement around the `firebase.initializeApp(config);`

```
  import * as firebase from 'firebase';

  const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DB_URL,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGE_ID,
  }

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

You shouldn't need to export these objects, once you initialise the app it should be usable within the project without exporting.

```
  const database = firebase.database();
  const auth = firebase.auth()

  export {firebase, auth, database };
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't initialize firebase more than once.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/228

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the development server solves the issue, if you have just written the code and trying to compile it throws this error. So you can try to exit the batch job and again restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this uncaught error related to firebase.Atlast Finally error should be solved.
Actually when we are using environment variables they should not pass in to bundle.js file which is a client side javascript file..We can use "DefinePlugin" which is a webpack plugin that should manually pass those env variables in to bundle.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code is just fine. Just print and check `process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL` and its exactly same as mentioned in firebase console. (If you are using create react app, dont forget to add `REACT_APP_` to all your env variables, https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/functions';
import 'firebase/storage';

const appConfiguration = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

export const session_type = firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL;

export const app = firebase.initializeApp(appConfiguration);
export const auth = app.auth();
export const db = app.firestore();
export const storage = app.storage();
```

will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I just paste the hardcode config and it worked for me

```
const config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBA2C8S7****************-gCw",
  authDomain: "e**********-2aa4c.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://************.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "ea********2aa4c",
  storageBucket: "ea************2aa4c.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1765********26",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have set environment variables using `require('dotenv').config({ 'path': '.env.development' })`. Also make sure that first you the set env variable as above, and then after insert firebaseConfig in Plugins:

```
 new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY), // this will set 'process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY' to actual key in firebase.js cause we do not directly set those value here to make it secure excluding .env files.    
  'process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN),
  'process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL),
  'process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID),
  'process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET),
  'process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID),
  'process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID),
  'process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID)
})` )
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason databaseURL read string values in "",
for example if we write:

```
const fbAuthDomain = "text";
const fbDatabaseURL = "text";

const firebaseConfig = {
  authDomain: fbAuthDomain,
  databaseURL: fbDatabaseURL
};

// and then:

console.log(firebaseConfig.authDomain); // returns "text"
console.log(firebaseConfig.databaseURL); // returns text
```

sorry for js example

for me, helped doing variable fbDatabaseURL in json from there i process.env in config - not:

```
{
  "fbDatabaseURL": "\"https://someurl.firebasedatabase.app\""
}
```

but:

```
{
  "fbDatabaseURL": "https://someurl.firebasedatabase.app"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Same issue here but after putting firebaseconfig in `componentDidMount()` it will solved.

```
componentDidMount(){

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL:process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const myitem = firebase.database().ref('items/').once('value',snapshot=>{
  console.log(snapshot.val())
})
```

}

Comment: what does `componentDidMount` has to do with this?

Answer (score -2):

In the firebase.js, when I removed the blank between databaseURL: and process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL., it worked.

```
const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL:process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
};
```

Comment: How could that possibly be a solution??