# Firebase Google Authentication with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

This is my Firebase file. I'm following a tutorial and I did the same. But I'm getting an error.

"Be sure to include authDomain when calling firebase.initializeApp(), by following the instructions in the Firebase console."

I think something might have changed since the video was uploaded 1 year ago. If you help me, I'll really relax

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/firestore"

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAİN,
databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_SENDER_ID,
appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export default firebase;
```

This is sign-in component

```
import React from 'react';
import { signInWithGoogle } from "../../firebase/firebase"
import FormInput from '../form-input/FormInput';
import Button from '../custom-button/Button';



import './SignIn.styles.scss';

class SignIn extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        };
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ email: '', password: '' });
    };

    handleChange = event => {
        const { value, name } = event.target;

        this.setState({ [name]: value });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='sign-in'>
                <h2>I already have an account</h2>
                <span>Sign in with your email and password</span>

                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <FormInput
                        name='email'
                        type='email'
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        value={this.state.email}
                        label='email'
                        required
                    />
                    <FormInput
                        name='password'
                        type='password'
                        value={this.state.password}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        label='password'
                        required
                    />
                    <Button type='submit'> Sign in </Button>
                    <Button onClick={signInWithGoogle} > Sign in With Google </Button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SignIn;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question. The main reason is using React_app environment variables. I tried to see in the console but the auth domain URL returned undefined. I corrected and it works now. Take a look .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911490/firebase-databaseurl-configuring-firebase